# Using TabController Template in Xcode - How to link objects back to the ViewController instead of TabController?

Tags: iphone, interface, tabs, controller, builder

IOS/IB Question - To clarify my question I'll use the following example. I created a new project using the TabController template.  I then create the "IBOutlet UILabel *mylabel" declaration in the header of my first ViewController.  I can see the "mylabel" show up in the TabController's "Connections" list in IB's inspector, but the "mylabel" doesn't show up in the FirstViewController's "Connections" list in IB.  What's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a new empty tab bar app in Xcode using iOS sdk 4.2, added IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;  to FirstViewController.h, *built* the app, then opened MainWindow.xib, went to the connections inspector (CMD-2), clicked on the tabbar object, and I don't see myLabel, click on FirstViewController, and I see myLabel like you'd expect.

Sometimes I find that I need to exit IB, buid the project, and restart IB in order for IBOutlets to properly show up in IB.

Comment: I see "mylabel" in inspector when I click on the FirstViewController under "Tab Bar" while in the MainWindow.xib file, but shouldn't I see it in "File's Owner" inspector while in the FirstView.xib file?

Comment: In my test project, FirstView.xib File's Owner is "UIViewController", not FirstViewController.    After changing it to FirstViewController, then myLabel is visible in the Connections Inspector

Comment: I just found that a few minutes ago and was just going to write back my findings.  Interesting that the default template didn't set that up.  Thanks for being there for us!